# Wifi is connected but there is no internet access Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, internet, iwlwifi

WiFi is connected but can't access to internet, the Ethernet is working properly.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 54:e1:ad:68:66:d6
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.0-41-generic firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:94104000-94104fff memory:94100000-94103fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 78
       serial: cc:2f:71:a7:15:ed
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-41-generic firmware=36.ca7b901d.0 8265-36.ucode ip=192.168.225.45 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:135 memory:94000000-94001fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 9
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 2a:6b:c6:a1:75:64
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.13.0-41-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.126.243 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.225.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.225.45 metric 600
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB:~$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 54:e1:ad:68:66:d6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether cc:2f:71:a7:15:ed brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

[OS DETAILS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Fa3.jpg)

Comment: Please be more specific. What make/model is the WiFi card, which drivers are installed, what have you already tried and did not fix the problem?

Comment: @PasWei updated the question

Comment: Is there a WiFi router within range? What does `ip route;ip link` show? Please [edit] your question to add information, do not use Add commrent.

Comment: question updated with more details @waltinator

Answer (score 1):

fixed my issue by updating my drivers using

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the resolver configuration was faulty.

Changing the resolv.conf file fixed this Issue for me.

`$ cd /etc`  
`$ sudo nano resolv.conf`

Change the Content as following:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=iergu6AIook)

Comment: this is a temporary fix btw, it will be overwritten next time